# EF Database context not saving update

Tags: entity-framework

I have some simple code I am using to update a profile picture that is saved in my database as a byte[]. For some odd reason it runs through my code with no errors at all but the database is not updated with the new picture that the user has chosen.

```
Client client = db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == User.Identity.Name);
if (client != null)
{
    client.ProfileImage = bytes;
    db.Clients.Attach(client);
    var entry = db.Entry(client);
    entry.Property(e => e.ProfileImage).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is the code for the Client entity class:

```
public partial class Client
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Client()
    {
        Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int? StripeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Guid UserID { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }

    public virtual StripeInfo StripeInfo { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Also after debugging the code I can see that the profile image is being set to the correct byte[] and the client.ProfileImage then contains the correct byte[], but as soon as db.SaveChanges() is called, client.ProfileImage is immediately set back to what it originally was. No errors occur or anything so I really can't figure out why this would be happening.

**7/4/2017**

Here are some additional things I have tried after looking on the internet some more:

1) Create a new database context instance to make the update.
2) Dispose of the original database context and create a new one to make the update.

Neither of the above attempts have worked. The ProfileImage property is still just set back to the original value when db.SaveChanges() is called.

Comment: Please show us the code for the entity `Client`, and if the context has any custom code in it.

Comment: @DavidG Just added the code for the Client entity class. My database context does not have any custom code.

Comment: @DavidG Wow I just noticed the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] line above the profile image....that is of course the problem. I had no idea it was there.

Comment: You're right! Add an answer and I will change the accepted answer and give you the bounty. Sorry about that.

Comment: @DavidG If you post an answer I'll accept it so you get the bounty. I wouldn't have noticed the issue if you didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `ProfileImage` property of your entity has an attribute applied to it:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

Which, [from the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx), is telling Entity Framework:

> **Computed**: The database generates a value when a row is inserted or updated.

You just need to remove that attribute completely.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code ? :

```
Client client = db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == User.Identity.Name);
if (client != null)
{
    client.ProfileImage = bytes;    
    var entry = db.Entry(client);
    entry.Property(e => e.ProfileImage).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If `client` has been already loaded from context then no need to attach it !

Comment: I just gave that a shot and it still does not update the database.

Comment: Any other ideas? I am not finding anything online. It doesn't make sense to me that it isn't working.